# Is CnosDB support geospatial datatype or method?

Tags: database, time-series, geospatial, cnosdb

Many common databases support geospatial types or geospatial methods, as a time series database, does CnosDB support geospatial datatype or method？

I have gathered some information for reference only：

Redis geospatial： https://redis.io/docs/data-types/geospatial/
Redis geospatial indexes let you store coordinates and search for them. This data structure is useful for finding nearby points within a given radius or bounding box.

MongoDB： https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/geospatial-queries/
In MongoDB, you can store geospatial data as GeoJSON objects or as legacy coordinate pairs.

Apache Arrow：
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/working-with-arrow-in-arcgis.htm
ArcGIS with Apache Arrow can support geospatial datatype.

I hope the team can give information about geospatial and how to use it, and if it is not supported, whether there are plans for it.